# GROUP BY is causing blank fields in results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I am working on trying to fix a problem in the below code.
The first 3000 or so records for the `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID` column are coming up blank/empty when running the query.
All other columns seem to be populating correctly.
I believe this is being caused by the group by which is needed for the sum aggregate.
Is there another way I can go about this which prevents the `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID` column from coming up blank?

```
Select ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID,
       I_SERVICE_DT,
       I_PRODUCT_I,
       sum(Claim_Count) as 'Total Claim Count'
--into #temp_claims
from reporting.dbo.vcbt
where YEAR (I_SERVICE_DT) = Cast(Datepart(yyyy,GETDATE())as varchar(4))
and O_CLAIM_ITEM_RESP_STATUS_CD  <> 'x' 
and PLAN_ID not in('PH13-800W', 'PH13-OGBW', 'PH13-800WL', 'PH13-OGBWL', 'PH13-OGBWA', 'PH13-OGBWM', 'PH13-800WM', 'PH13-800WA')
Group by ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID, I_PRODUCT_I, I_SERVICE_DT
order by ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID, I_SERVICE_DT, I_PRODUCT_I
```

Comment: Is `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID` blank in your table for many rows? It most undoubtedly is. What would you prefer the result set show instead of null?

Comment: The `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID` field should always have a value.  I am going to run a query against the `reporting.dbo.vcbt` view to be sure.  I did notice when I take out everything else from the select statement and take out the group by clause, there are no blank `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID` fields.  This leads me to believe the group by clause is causing the issue.  It's not that I prefer it to show something else, I need it to show the correct `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID`.

Comment: What happens if you only take out the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: A group by will not cause a value to suddenly change into an empty string or null. There must be some rows in this state. What does this return? select count(*) from reporting.dbo.vcbt where ISNULL(ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID, '') = ''

Comment: I think you guys are right.  The query I created did show that there were some blank values in the table for `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID`.  Sean, I am running your query now, but I see where you are going and I believe this is the culprit.

Comment: Code looks like fine to me, field `ADJ_CARDHOLDER_ID` isn't being manipulated here so it must come from NULL records.